# Alternative definition for closed function when the upper-level set is closed instead of the sublevel set?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convex-analysis

A function $f:X\to \mathbb R$ is closed if it satisfies $\{x\in X||f(x)\leq a\}$ is closed for any $a$.

What is the name of the property for $f$ if it satisfies $\{x\in X||f(x)\geq a\}$ is closed for any $a$?

Comment: This question is duplicated. Please erase the other one.

Comment: @JeanMarie Sincerely apology! I didn't know that I submitted this twice.

Comment: @HighGPA It seems some questions are posted twice due to a possible system issue. For more details, see the main Meta post [New question asking form sometimes leads to accidental double posts of questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346338/562482). It's possible this issue applies to your case instead of you doing anything incorrect to have caused the double posting to occur.

Comment: This definition of "closed" is specific for convex analysis. In the rest of analysis, it's called "lower semi-continuous". Predictably, there's also "upper semi-continuous", but that would be more relevant for *concave* functions. Advice: concentrate on concepts, not on names.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I updated the tag based on your comment. The reason why I need a name is I have to frequently mention this concept in a paper and I don't want to create a new name by myself. It will be silly if there is already a name in literature.